# Pub Error: Incompatible version constraints on analyzer

Tags: dart, constraints, incompatibility, dart-pub

I have a very weird problem. I have some dependencies that previous to adding a new dependency work well, but as soon as I add a new one (in this specific case `async_await`) I get an `Incompatible version constraints on analyzer` error when using `pub get`. The curious thing is: `async_await` is NOT an incompatible constraint!

> Pub get failed, [1] Resolving dependencies... Incompatible version
>   constraints on analyzer:
>   - angular 1.0.0 depends on version >=0.15.0 <0.19.0
>   - di 3.3.1 depends on version >=0.15.0 <0.22.0
>   - redstone_mapper 0.1.1 depends on version >=0.13.0 <0.14.0

Why doesn't this error show when I remove `async_await` (this same thing happened with another import) if the constraints should still fail?

**Update**

Running `pub upgrade` reveals another problem

> Resolving dependencies... 
>   Incompatible version constraints on analyzer: 
>   - angular 1.0.0 depends on version >=0.15.0 <0.19.0 
>   - async_await 0.0.0 depends on version >=0.22.4 <0.23.0

**Pubspec.yaml**

```
name: aristadart
description: A sample web application
dependencies:
  angular: 1.0.0
  browser: any
  di: any
  fp: any
  http: any
  mongo_dart: any
  redstone: any
  redstone_mapper: any
  redstone_mapper_mongo: any
  shelf_static: any


transformers:
- redstone_mapper
- angular:
    html_files:
    - lib/components/login/login.html
    - lib/components/login/nuevo_usuario.html
    - lib/components/home/home.html
    - lib/components/evento/evento.html
    - lib/components/vista/vista.html
```

Comment: Can you please post your `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: I tried it with the `dependency_overrides` from my answer and it worked. Do you still get an error?

Answer (score 8):

There is just no set of dependencies where all version constraints fit.
I solve such problems by pinpointing the version of some dependencies to make the life easier for `pub get`/`pub upgrade` and add some `dependency_overrides` to force-solve some discrepancies.
Add overrides one by one until no more errors occur.

In your case I had to add quite a few overrides

```yml
dependency_overrides:
  analyzer: ^0.22.4
  barback: ^0.15.2+2
  code_transformers: ^0.2.3+2
  di: ^3.3.3
  route_hierarchical: ^0.6.1
```

This way you force packages to use dependencies they are not tested with but it's the only way to solve it (besides updating the dependencies itself to use newer versions, but this is usually controlled by others).

Answer (score 5):

Pub's version solver is doing a global analysis of all of the version constraints in all of your dependencies. Not just that, but each *version* of a dependency has different constraints.

This means constraint failures can be non-local. It's not just that `async_await` has a constraint that causes a problem. It could be that:

- `async_await` adds a constraint on `foo`.
- That forces you to take a different version of `foo` than you would otherwise.
- That in turn gives you a different set of constraints coming from `foo`.
- Those in turn tweak some of the versions of other dependencies.
- Which then lead to other different constraints...
- And so on...

In practice, most of the errors like this we've seen recently seem to have the analyzer package as their lynchpin. The analyzer folks rev that package really frequently (or at least did for a while) and change its minor version often. That means there are a lot of packages that depend on disjoint sets of analyzer versions.

Like @Günter suggests, the workaround is to override a couple of dependencies, so that can cause its own problems. (It basically turns a "pub get time" failure into a possible runtime failure.)